# Pandas subtract DataFrame column from lookup DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction, lookup-tables

Given a dataframe `test` and another dataframe `lookup`

```
test = pd.DataFrame( [['a',1],
                      ['a',2], 
                      ['b',9]], columns = ['id', 'n'])

lookup_mins = pd.DataFrame( [['a',1], 
                             ['b',9], 
                             ['c',7]] , columns = ['id', 'n'])
```

trying to subtract each value `n` in `test` by the value `n` with matching `id` in `lookup_mins` using

```
s = lookup_mins.groupby(['id'])['n'].transform('min')
test['n2'] = test['n'] - s
```

Expected result,

```
id n n2
a  1 0
a  2 1
b  9 0
```

but getting instead

```
id n n2
a  1 0
a  2 -7
b  9  9
```

How to subtract `test` and `lookup_mins` to get the expected result as stated above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with aggregate `min`:

```
s = lookup_mins.groupby(['id'])['n'].min()
test['n2'] = test['n'] - test['id'].map(s)
print (test)
  id  n  n2
0  a  1   0
1  a  2   1
2  b  9   0
```